# save changes to instance of class reflect changes

Tags: c#

friends i'm using class and ado.net
i'm using data table connection oledb and so on

when I take instance of this class using form load to load data on a form control like text box and combo and so on
i do some operation using this instance like add record delete record edit record

i have also navigation button move2first move2last and so on

what is my problem:
my problem when do insert delete update on this instance of class this changes not reflect on the instance it self
when moving using button move i see the same record

how to update the instance of class to reflect the changes

this is class

```
    class dataConnection
    {
        public int affectedrecord;
        //Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
        public OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.dPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=azouz(2016)");
       OleDbDataAdapter da;
       DataTable dt =new DataTable() ;
       OleDbCommand com;
        int intRow = 0;
        DataRow r;

        public DataTable  loadingdata(string sql)
        {
          dt.Clear();  
          da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn);
          da.Fill(dt);
          return dt;
        }


public void saverecord(string sql,string[]para,string[]val) 
      {
          cn.Open();
          com = new OleDbCommand();
          com.CommandText = sql;
          com.Connection = cn;
          com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          for (int i = 0; i< para.Count(); i++)
          {
              com.Parameters.AddWithValue(para[i], val[i]);
          }

          affectedrecord = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
          if (affectedrecord > 0) 
          {
              affectedrecord = 1;
          }
          cn.Close();
      }

      public void EditRecord(string sql, string [] para,string []val)
      {
          cn.Open();
          com = new OleDbCommand();
          com.CommandText = sql;
          com.Connection = cn;
          com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          int x = para.Count();
          for (int i = 0; i < para.Count(); i++)
          {
              com.Parameters.AddWithValue(para[i], val[i]);
          }
          affectedrecord = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
          if (affectedrecord > 0)
          {
              affectedrecord = 1;
          }
          cn.Close();

      }

      public void DeleteRecord(string sql,string [] para,string []val)
      {
          cn.Open();
          com = new OleDbCommand();
          com.CommandText = sql;
          com.Connection = cn;
          com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          for (int i =0;i<1;i++)
          {
              com.Parameters.AddWithValue(para[i], val[i]);

          }
          affectedrecord = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

          if (affectedrecord > 0)
          {
              affectedrecord = 1;
          }
          cn.Close();

      }
```

operation on form

```
 public partial class frmRegStore : Window
    {
        public frmRegStore()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #region Variables
        //     'هذا النموذج يعتمد علي
        //' class
        //' c worktable 
        //'لملئ النموذج وورقة البيانات بالسجلات


        //'تعريف كائن من الكلاس
        dataConnection TotalWork = new dataConnection();   
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow r;
        #endregion
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] para = { "@storeName" };
            string[] val = { this.txtStoreName.Text };
            dataConnection Stores = new dataConnection();
            Stores.saverecord("insert into Stores (StoreName)values(?);", para, val);
            if (Stores.affectedrecord > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("تم اضافة السجل بنجاح");

            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dt = TotalWork.loadingdata("Select * from Stores");
            r = TotalWork.Move2First();
            showData();
        }
        public void showData()
        {

            if ((r != null))
            {
                this.txtStoreID.Text = r[0].ToString();
                this.txtStoreName.Text = r[1].ToString();
            }

        }

        private void btnLast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            r = TotalWork.Move2Last();
            showData();
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            r = TotalWork.Move2Next();
            showData();
        }

        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            r = TotalWork.Move2Previous();
            showData();
        }

        private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            r = TotalWork.Move2First();
            showData();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string[] para = { "@storeID" };
            string[] val = { this.txtStoreID.Text };
            dataConnection Stores = new dataConnection();
            Stores.saverecord("Delete from Stores where StoreId =?", para, val);
            if (Stores.affectedrecord > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("تم حذف السجل بنجاح");

            }

        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] para = {"@storeName", "@storeID" };
            string[] val = { this.txtStoreName.Text,this.txtStoreID.Text };
            dataConnection Stores = new dataConnection();
            Stores.saverecord("update Stores set StoreName = @storeName where StoreId =@storeID", para, val);
            if (Stores.affectedrecord > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("تم تعديل السجل بنجاح");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the offending code, state CLEARLY what you expect the results to be, and what the actual results are

Comment: reece cottan i edit the post to see all code

Comment: TotalWork is the class instance of dataconnection